# org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' ... Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

The script was running before but after I left it for a while(a month) this error has been popping up.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script4.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:905) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:627) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:314) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:257) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:336) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:181) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:211) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) ~


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:871) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:506) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1432) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:262) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.lambda$new$16(CompilationUnit.java:738) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:901) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
```

I hope somebody could help me debug this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your system got update of the Java runtime to some new version which is not compatible with your version of JMeter.

Try downgrading your Java, the minimal version you can run [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

Comment: I recently installed Java 17 but I removed it in my environment variables and now my current java version is "1.8.0_291". Are there more steps that I should do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed two versions of java 8 or 11, Then please switch to lower version 8 and then run tests.
This solution worked for me

Comment: This is a duplicative answer of one that already exists. If an existing answer helped you, instead, upvote that answer.